# Issues chaining object rendered from express in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, mustache

I'm having trouble finding the solution for a simple issue I'm currently having when trying to chain an object rendered from express in my handlebars file.

The object I'm trying to chain looks like so:

```
"generalContentOfferOne": {
  "subCopy": {
    "en-us": "Test Copy",
    "bahasa": "Bergabunglah dalam..."
  }
}
```

In my handlebars file, `{{distributorJSON.generalContentOfferOne.subCopy}}` renders `Object object`, which it should.

I have a localization variable I'm also rendering to handlebars. It will either be `en-us` or `bahasa` based on route. Anyways, now that I have this localization value, I figured I could use bracket notation to render the dynamic value in the object above. For example:

`{{ distributorJSON.generalContentOfferOne.subCopy[{{localization}}] }}`

Also tried:

`{{ distributorJSON.generalContentOfferOne.subCopy.{{localization}} }}`

These aren't working.. I'm guessing handlebars has it's own specific way to chain dynamic values? Or at least I hope so. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a default solution for this. So I built a handlebars helper.

Helper:

```
exports.returnDynamicPropValue = function(object, localization){
  return object[localization];
}
```

Handlebars template:

```
{{ returnDynamicPropValue distributorJSON.generalContentOfferOne.subCopy localization }}
```